# Directly Putting Data in AppEngine's Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

The AppEngine's standard API assumes files are uploaded from an HTML form.
I'm trying to post a file to the blobstore from a REST API method that can be called by a non Html client (Flash, iPhone, etc.)

The code I'm trying to get working:

```
# Get the blobstore upload url    
upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url("/activities/upload_finished");

# Make sync call to the blobstore url to post our image
result = urlfetch.fetch(url=upload_url,
                        payload=request.FILES,
                        method=urlfetch.POST,
                        headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'})
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ValueError: Invalid boundary in

Any idea?
Has anyone tried posting to the blobstore not through a web form?

> multipart form: ''

Answer (score 7):

[App Engine (version 1.4.3) allows you to directly write data to the blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore).
You no longer need to use the upload url method.

Comment: right, please notice hat this feature is marked as Experimental (don't know what does it mean)

Comment: @Yonatan It means "Don't come crying if it doesn't work and break your site" :) and also "We might change the API until final relase"

Comment: looks like it's deprecated now

Answer (score 4):

You can't make a regular post into a multipart form simply by specifying the content type - you're just submitting URL-encoded data with the wrong content type.

You'll need to assemble a proper multipart form - using the [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email) module or by hand, like [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680305/using-multipartposthandler-to-post-form-data-with-python).