# Python library for HTTP support - including Content-Encoding

Tags: python, http

I have a scraper, which queries different websites. Some of them varyingly use Content-Encoding. And since I'm trying to simulate an AJAX query and need to mimic Mozilla, I need full support. There are multiple HTTP libraries for Python, but neither seems complete:

httplib seems pretty low level, more like a HTTP packet sniffer really.

urllib2 is some sort of elaborate hoax. There are a dozen handlers for various web client functions, but mandatory HTTP features like Content-Encoding appearantly aren't.

mechanize: is nice, already somehwat overkill for my tasks, but only supports CE 'gzip'.

httplib2: sounded most promising, but actually fails on 'deflate' encoding, because of the disparity of raw deflate and zlib streams.

So are there any other options? I can't believe I'm expected to reimplement workarounds for above libraries. And it's not a good idea to distribute patched versions alongside my application, because packagers might remove it again if the according library is available as separate distribution package.

I almost don't dare to say, but the http functions API in PHP is much nicer. And besides Content-Encoding:*, I might somewhen need multipart/form-data too. So, is there a comprehensive 3rd party library for http retrieval?

Comment: Second question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680305/using-multipartposthandler-to-post-form-data-with-python

Comment: @Metalshark: that poster module seems cool+simple. bookmarked. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider either invoking a child process of [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) or using [python bindings for libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/python/).

From [this description](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html) cURL seems to support gzip and deflate.

Comment: I prefer wget over curl for cmdline work, and thus was a little relunctant because PycURL is also a non-standard extension. But it's probably the most mature and feature-complete solution around, so really the best choice.

Answer (score -1):

[Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) might work.  Just throwing it out there.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is for parsing HTML and similar markups. It doesn't deal with HTTP.