# unable to send data using urllib and urllib2 (python)

Tags: python, file-upload, urllib2, urllib

Hello everybody (first post here).

I am trying to send data to a webpage. This webpage request two fields (a file and an e-mail address) if everything is ok the webpage returns a page saying "everything is ok" and sends a file to the provided e-mail address. I execute the code below and I get nothing in my e-mail account.

```
import urllib, urllib2

params = urllib.urlencode({'uploaded': open('file'),'email': 'user@domain.com'})
req = urllib2.urlopen('http://webpage.com', params)
print req.read()
```

the print command gives me the code of the home page (I assume instead it should give the code of the "everything is ok" page).

I think (based o google search) the poster module should do the trick but I need to keep dependencies to a minimum, hence I would like a solution using standard libraries (if that is possible).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you missing any headers?  'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Please don't post your solution in the question.  You *can* and *should* answer your own question, if none of the answers below helped.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have just fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your answers. I solve my problem using the mechanize library.

```
import mechanize 

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('webpage.com') 

email='user@domain.com'

br.select_form(nr=0) 
br['email'] = email 
br.form.add_file(open('filename'), 'mime-type', 'filename')    
br.form.set_all_readonly(False) 
br.submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This site could checks Referer, User-Agent and Cookies.

Way to handle all of this is using `urllib2.OpenerDirector` which you can get by `urllib2.build_opener`.

```
# Cookies handle
cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
CookieProcessor = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)
# Build OpenerDirector
opener = urllib2.build_opener(CookieProcessor)
# Valid User-Agent from Firefox 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 10.04
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100723 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.8'
# Referer says that you send request from web-site title page
referer = 'http://webpage.com'
opener.addheaders = [
    ('User-Agent', user_agent),
    ('Referer', referer),
    ('Accept-Charset', 'utf-8')
]
```

Then prepare parameters with `urlencode` and send request by `opener.open(params)`

Documentation for Python 2.7: [cookielib](http://docs.python.org/library/cookielib.html), [OpenerDirector](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#openerdirector-objects)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but your solution does not solve my problem. I think (i have just realized) that my problem have something to do with the fact that the page needs the data to be encoded as "multipart/form-data"

Comment: OK. Then you can use what was advised: [MultiPartPostHandler](http://peerit.blogspot.com/2007/07/multipartposthandler-doesnt-work-for.html).  It is few lines of code so it isn't really dependency.  Consider it just your own class which you wrote yesterday for convenient file uploading :)

Comment: I am trying to use this solution (with some minor changes, but still not working properly) [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680305/using-multipartposthandler-to-post-form-data-with-python/681182#681182