# post data to web for processing

Tags: python, web

I am a newbie to web development, so please be mercy if the following question sounds a bit naive. How can I post to a web form using python? I know the web form is something like this, and I want to upload a local file for it to be processed online and get the returned data

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" id="chooser" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"  />
</form>
```

Here's what I have for my python program so far.

```
upfile = urllib.urlencode( {'file':path/to/my/local/file})
filehandle = urllib.urlopen('http://www.comdroid.org/', upfile)
soup = BeautifulSoup(filehandle)
print soup
```

I want to see the returned results, but the current code snippet only gives me the result without processing my uploaded file. Is there anything I am missing

------------UPDATE----------------
Here is how I do it now

```
import urllib2
import urllib 
import requests
import os
files1 ={'file':open('/opt/apps/au.com.psyborg.sbc-5.apk','rb')‌​}
#response= os.system("curl --form   file=@/opt/apps/au.com.psyborg.sbc-5.apk --form submit=Upload www.comdroid.org/process.php")
req = requests.post('comdroid.org/process.php', files = files1) 
print req.text
```

---

The weird thing is I cannot do it with request, the server complains my file is not .apk file, which it actually is. But if I switch to curl using os.system as commented out, it works! So I doubt I am missing something here in request. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the form's `action` property, it's going to `process.php` - so you'll need to send your file upload to `http://www.comdroid.org/process.php`.

Doing file uploads with the standard library is a bit of a pain - if you're allowed to, I would recommend using [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) for this - they even [have an example of what you're asking for in their documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

I also found [this SO answer on how to do it with the mechanize library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6498163/240418), and [a code sample that might help if you want to do it with the standard library](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306-http-client-to-post-using-multipartform-data/).

Comment: thanks, I understand the whole frame now,but was still not able to get the result desired. What happened is that the server keeps rejecting my request by saying that my file is not required .apk file.(which it actually is.

Comment: Is it possible that the way "request" encoded the .apk file somehow twisted it and the .apk file cannot be recognized by the server?

Comment: No, requests shouldn't do anything to alter the contents of your file - either the detection logic on the form you're uploading to is wrong, or the file you're trying to upload is not an apk. What is the actual error message?

Comment: <b>PLEASE RETURN TO THE PREVIOUS PAGE AND SUBMIT A VALID .APK FILE</b>

Comment: my file should be right.. it is indeed an .apk file. In fact I tried with the same file using curl, and it worked