# How can I use python to "send" data (images) to ImageBam.com

Tags: python, urllib2, mechanize, multipartform-data

I've read a lot about multipart/forms, mechanize and twill, but I couldn' findout howto implement a code.

[Using MultipartPostHandler to POST form-data with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680305/using-multipartposthandler-to-post-form-data-with-python)

First I Tried to fill the forms on

`www.imagebam.com/basic-upload`

I can fill the forms but cant send the data really even if I submit() it.

after looking the source code at the page above, I realized all I need to do is "post" data in correct content-type to the page (correct me if Im wrong please)

```
http://www.imagebam.com/sys/upload/save
```

directly..

I tried to use poster.py, but couldnt understand how this stuff works. I can use mechanize and twill a little  bit, but I am stucked since this is more complex than simple form posting, I think.

So my questions;

**-How can I use poster.py (or user-created multipartform classes) to upload images to imagebam.com**

**-or any other alternative solutions :)**

Answer (score 0):

Mechanize is not the right tool for the task.

Implementing http://code.google.com/p/imagebam-api/ in python is way more robust.

The examples are in PHP/curl, converting them to python/urllib2 should be trivial.

Comment: thank you for comment :) I solved it by using 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850239/trying-to-post-multipart-form-data-in-python-wont-post

poster module :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely completely on third party libraries like mechanize. Either implement its official api in python [API ImageBam](http://code.google.com/p/imagebam-api/)
or see this project developed in pyqt4 [pymguploader](http://code.google.com/p/pymguploader/) to upload image and than try to implement yourself.

Comment: thank you for comment :) I found imageban api hard to understand cuz I dont know anything about "oatuh" stuff. I solved problem by using poster.py :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! I did it. I used 
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850239/trying-to-post-multipart-form-data-in-python-wont-post).

Here is the code:

```
>>> from poster.encode import multipart_encode
>>> from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
>>> import urllib2
>>> register_openers()
<urllib2.OpenerDirector instance at 0x02CDD828>
>>> datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"file[]": open("D:\hedef\myfile.jpg","rb"),"content_type":"1","thumb_size":"350"})
>>> request = urllib2.Request("http://www.imagebam.com/sys/upload/save", datagen, headers)
>>> print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Now all I need to do is use BeautifulSoup to fecth the thumbnail codes :)