# Upload file to a Tomcat server using python

Tags: python, servlets, urllib

I have written a java servlet that uploads multiple files, I used cURL to upload the file

`curl -F filedata=@myfile.txt http://127.0.0.1/test_Server/multipleupload`  this uploads the file to a folder  `uploads` that is located  in the `webapps` folder. I'm in the middle of writing a python module that can be used instead of curl, the reason being this server is going to be used by a build farm so using cURL is not an option and the sane goes for using pycURL. The python module I'm working on was previously written for doing this on pastebin , so all i'm doing is editing this to use my server and it looks like `urllib` doesn't do `multipart/form-data`?. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great, I haven't posted the code but if anyone wants it I will do so, There isn't much in that code as a start all I did was changed teh URL to my server and thats when I found out that its using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (Thank you Wireshark ! )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using MultipartPostHandler to POST form-data with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680305/using-multipartposthandler-to-post-form-data-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Request-class](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) to send your own headers. Maybe you wanna use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), it makes life easier.

**EDIT:** [uploading files with requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

Comment: Just one question , the request seems to be included in urllib3 , do the machines need urlib3 installed in order for this to work ?

Comment: requests is included in urllib3, but they don't need urllib3.