# Make an http POST request to upload a file using Python urllib/urllib2

Tags: python, http, post, urllib2, urllib

I would like to make a POST request to upload a file to a web service (and get response) using Python. For example, I can do the following POST request with `curl`:

```
curl -F "file=@style.css" -F output=json http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator
```

How can I make the same request with python urllib/urllib2? The closest I got so far is the following:

```
with open("style.css", 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
post_data = {"file": content, "output": "json"}
request = urllib2.Request("http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator", \
                          data=urllib.urlencode(post_data))
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

I got a HTTP Error 500 from the code above. But since my `curl` command succeeds, it must be something wrong with my python request?

I am quite new to this topic and my question may have very simple answers or mistakes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some digging around, it seems [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/688193/4195568) solved my problem. It turns out I need to have the multipart encoder setup properly.

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
import urllib2

register_openers()

with open("style.css", 'r') as f:
    datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"file": f})
    request = urllib2.Request("http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator", \
                              datagen, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: Don't forget to close the `style.css` file?

Comment: @Vladius The file will be closed automatically because it is used as a context manager. See documentation on [the `with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#with).

Comment: Im really new to python. I ran the above seemingly successful. What should i expect now? Where can i verify it works.

Comment: poster is for py2, poster3 is supposed to be working for py3 but development has stopped since 2018 and it's not working anymore. see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038209/)

Comment: For a Python3 implementation, with either requests or urllib.request, have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77881652/2128591

Answer (score 13):

Personally I think you should consider the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) library to post files.

```
url = 'http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator'
files = {'file': open('style.css')}
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Uploading files using `urllib2` is not impossible but quite a complicated task: http://pymotw.com/2/urllib2/#uploading-files

Comment: Thanks, @Wolph. I just tried requests library, but still got an HTTP 500 error.. So my question should probably be rephrased as, what are the differences between the request we made in python and that made by curl? Thanks.

Comment: Well, you have the `output=json` in your curl request, that's not in the Python request so that's probably the difference. Glad you have it working now though :)

Comment: I have raw `.jpg` file in the form of `ndarray` variable. how can I `POST` this in a similar way?

Comment: @Santhosh using `ndarray.tobytes()` is probably easiest, but you can also use a `fh = StringIO(); ndarray.tofile(fh)` and use the `fh` as a file object

Comment: @Wolph In case I have just the image in the form of `ndarray` without any format like `.jpg` or `.png` how would I upload it, then?

Comment: @Santhosh the raw image should be in `.bmp` (bitmap) format. That quickly gets bandwidth intensive though, using a temporary `.png` file might be better

Comment: The author has clearly identified that the file needs to be submitted via urllib/urllib2. The `requests` library doesn't exist in Python 2.7. And installing it externally is not an option in many cases.

Comment: @real4x: the author is not the only person reading this question and it's answers. For most people using `requests` is the better option which is why I gave this answer and example of how to use it. Additionally, I linked to the complicated code to make it work

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are multiple ways to do it. As mentioned above, you can send the file in "multipart/form-data". However, the target service may not be expecting this type, in which case you may try some more approaches.

**Pass the file object**

urllib2 can accept a file object as `data`. When you pass this type, the library reads the file as a binary stream and sends it out. However, it will *not* set the proper `Content-Type` header. Moreover, if the `Content-Length` header is missing, then it will try to access the `len` property of the object, which doesn't exist for the files. That said, you must provide both the `Content-Type` and the `Content-Length` headers to have the method working:

```
import os
import urllib2

filename = '/var/tmp/myfile.zip'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
    'Content-Length': os.stat(filename).st_size,
}
request = urllib2.Request('http://localhost', open(filename, 'rb'),
                          headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

**Wrap the file object**

To not deal with the length, you may create a simple wrapper object. With just a little change you can adapt it to get the content from a string if you have the file loaded in memory.

```
class BinaryFileObject:
  """Simple wrapper for a binary file for urllib2."""

  def __init__(self, filename):
    self.__size = int(os.stat(filename).st_size)
    self.__f = open(filename, 'rb')

  def read(self, blocksize):
    return self.__f.read(blocksize)

  def __len__(self):
    return self.__size
```

**Encode the content as base64**

Another way is encoding the `data` via `base64.b64encode` and providing `Content-Transfer-Type: base64` header. However, this method requires support on the server side. Depending on the implementation, the service can either accept the file and store it incorrectly, or return `HTTP 400`. E.g. the GitHub API won't throw an error, but the uploaded file will be corrupted.

Comment: One other thing to note is `base64` means +33.3% traffic. Especially if you're using some cloud hosting, it's going to cost quite a bit.