# urllib2 urlopen error: must be string or buffer, not instance

Tags: python, urllib2

I have a simple Python script as shown below which accesses a PHP script.

```
import urllib2
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
url="http://192.168.122.1/info.php/"
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"file": open("123.txt", 'r')})
request = urllib2.Request(url,datagen,headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = response.read();
print data
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 8, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
'_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1194, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1048, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1088, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1044, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 892, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 864, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not instance
```

What could be the reason for this? Or is it a problem with my PHP script.

This is my PHP script

```
<?php
        echo "Hello";
?>
```

Comment: do you want the responce of that site

Comment: @VigneshKalai yes . i am just returning a string..

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27052062/3460885

From this question , I had to add register_openers()  in the beginning.

Comment: Mark your own answer as acepted. ;)