# Issue while sending a file to an API

Tags: python, api, http-post, python-requests

I'm trying to send a file to an API and then get the response  - a CSV file
(I've seen [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050399/make-an-http-post-request-to-upload-a-file-using-python-urllib-urllib2) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477/send-file-using-post-from-a-python-script) about it but I couldn't make it work)

The examples in the documentation use httpie

```
http --timeout 600 -f POST http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/ data@path/to/file.csv
```

but when I'm using requests, I get an `400 Bad Request`

```
path = '/myfile.csv'
url = 'http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/'
files = {'file': open(path, 'rb')}
res = requests.post(url, data=files)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[You need to specify `files` keyword argument](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files), not `data` to post multipart/form-data request.

And the key should match: `file` -> `data`

```
path = 'path/to/file.csv'
url = 'http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/'
files = {'data': open(path, 'rb')}
#        ^^^^^^
res = requests.post(url, files=files)
#                        ^^^^^
```