# Port to Python 3.7, poster3.encode.multipart_encode, TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multipartform-data

I've been working on this for a long time--trying to get code from Python 2.7 to work on Python 3.7.

- Python 3.7.7
- Windows 10 (even though path definition below looks like unix)
- Trying to upload a .png file
- Exception: `memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

I've tried changing the types on each part of the multipart data. Made progress - multipart_encode is accepting all the input now, but the request is still failing. Have read much on this website and elsewhere, but can't get it to work. Can someone help me identify what part of the input needs modification and how to deal with it?

```
import base64
import simplejson
import urllib.request
import poster3

    
self.base64string = base64.standard_b64encode(
    ('%s:%s' % (self.username, self.password)).replace(
    '\n', '').encode())
    
self.base_URL = "https://%s/service"%self.hostname
self.PATH_ATTACHMENTS = '%s/rest/secure/v1/incidentNoteAttachments' % self.base_URL

path = '/usr/local/audit_data/'
filename = 'SN121838027160.png'
incidentNoteId = '14122370'

data = {
    'incidentNotes': {
    'id': incidentNoteId,
    },
    'name': filename,
}
opener = poster3.streaminghttp.register_openers()

datagen, headers = poster3.encode.multipart_encode(
    [('data', json.dumps(data).encode('UTF-8')),
     ('filename', (path + filename).encode('UTF-8')),
     ('file', open(path + filename, 'rb')])

req = urllib.request.Request(self.PATH_ATTACHMENTS, datagen, headers)
req.add_header('Authorization', 'Basic %s' % self.base64string.decode())

try:
    print(simplejson.loads(opener.open(req).read()))
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    pass
```

```
  File "C:\ltr_Python3\PCUBarcodeScanner\fracas_incidents.py", line 259, in createAttachment
    print(simplejson.loads(opener.open(req).read()))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1393, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1350, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1277, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1071, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 997, in send
    self.sock.sendall(d)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1031, in sendall
    with memoryview(data) as view, view.cast("B") as byte_view:
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

NOTE: I've corrected my entry with updated exception handling info:
I set a breakpoint in the Pycharm debugger at the location of the last stack trace entry. It successfully sends the 1st chunk and catches the exception on the 2nd. It then tries to send each character from the 2nd chunk. This is when the unhandled exception occurs. I've shown the try/except sendall() code snippet from the client.py module.

```
<module client.py send() method>

        try:
            self.sock.sendall(data)
        except TypeError:
            if isinstance(data, collections.abc.Iterable):
                for d in data:
                    self.sock.sendall(d)
            else:
                raise TypeError("data should be a bytes-like object "
                                "or an iterable, got %r" % type(data))
```

*While in the debugger, I noticed that the content of the 2nd chunk starts with the boundary value found in the body, but with leading '--'. Here's body.boundary up the stack in client.py 'aeb34cead7ec4add88be63165b77f974'.*

*Prior to the sendall() which results in the caught exception, here's the value of start of data (see below for full content):
'--aeb34cead7ec4add88be63165b77f974...'*

```
<1st chunk is OK>
    try:
        self.sock.sendall(data)

data = 
b'POST /service/rest/secure/v1/incidentNoteAttachments HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: <corporate website address removed>\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/3.7\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=8dbced5dd0a4409c8b01d83b784781b0\r\nContent-Length: 43956\r\nAuthorization: Basic b3J0X3VzZXI6Z3I4MTRvcnRfdXNlcg==\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'
```

```
<2nd chunk results in exception caught and attempt to send by character>
    try:
        self.sock.sendall(data)

data =
'--aeb34cead7ec4add88be63165b77f974
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
b\\'{"incidentNotes": {"id": "14122370"}, "name": "SN121838027160.png"}\\'
'
```

```
<1st character causes the exception>
    try:
        self.sock.sendall(data)
    except TypeError:
        if isinstance(data, collections.abc.Iterable):
            for d in data:
                self.sock.sendall(d)

d = 
'-'
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: SuperStormer, I don't see a stack trace. There's only the error message I provided which is caught as an exception. Please advise how to get the info you want.

Comment: Remove the try-except, as all it does is suppress a stack trace.

Comment: Also, try`print(simplejson.load(opener.open(req))`.

Comment: Of course, thanks! I've added the stack trace.

Comment: Have you tried using ```with memoryview(b"{}".format(data)) as ....```

Comment: @AsianCat That's stdlib code.

Comment: Oh I just guessed

Comment: Encode the Authorization header value.

Comment: @Niloct I had tried that. So I tried it again with the value and/or header type encoding as 'ascii' or 'UTF-8'. I get my previous errors on on the definition of the Authorization header with each case:
`req.add_header('Authorization'.encode('UTF-8'), 'Basic %s'.encode('UTF-8') % self.base64string.decode())
TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'`

Comment: I just added info from a debugging session showing the content of the data causing the exception.

Comment: Right. Found a possible reason for the exception, please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I read a bit about the `multipart_encode` method. Try this:

```
datagen, headers = poster3.encode.multipart_encode(
    [('data', json.dumps(data).encode('UTF-8')),
     ('filename', (path + filename).encode('UTF-8')),
     ('file', open(path + filename, 'rb'))])
```

(i.e. read the file in binary mode).

Keep the other original code as it is for now.

---

I did a little more digging on `poster3`:

https://atlee.ca/software/poster/#source-bugs

This is the link for reporting bugs, but you can see for yourself that the bitbucket repo has been deleted. So this seems abandoned code.

---

Even then, I've did a small debugging variation to see what was the issue. Run this reduced version of your original code:

```
import base64
import json # Needed this import
import poster3
import simplejson
import urllib.request

class X:
    def __init__(self):
        # dummy values
        self.username = 'username'
        self.password = 'password'
        self.hostname = 'localhost'

        self.base64string = base64.standard_b64encode(('%s:%s' % (self.username, self.password)).replace( '\n', '').encode())
            
        self.base_URL = "https://%s/service" % self.hostname
        self.PATH_ATTACHMENTS = '%s/rest/secure/v1/incidentNoteAttachments' % self.base_URL

        path = '/usr/local/audit_data/'
        filename = 'SN121838027160.png'
        incidentNoteId = '14122370'

        data = {
            'incidentNotes': {
            'id': incidentNoteId,
            },
            'name': filename,
        }
        opener = poster3.streaminghttp.register_openers()

        datagen, headers = poster3.encode.multipart_encode(
            [('data', json.dumps(data).encode()),
             ('filename', (path + filename).encode()),
             ('file', open(path + filename, 'rb'))])

        print(datagen, headers)

X()
```

Using Python 3.9.7 on Mac, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/teixeira/Downloads/Pessoal/etudes/etudes_py/stackoverflow/so_69038209.py", line 37, in <module>
    X()
  File "/Users/teixeira/Downloads/Pessoal/etudes/etudes_py/stackoverflow/so_69038209.py", line 30, in __init__
    datagen, headers = poster3.encode.multipart_encode(
  File "/Users/teixeira/Downloads/Pessoal/etudes/etudes_py/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poster3/encode.py", line 412, in multipart_encode
    headers = get_headers(params, boundary)
  File "/Users/teixeira/Downloads/Pessoal/etudes/etudes_py/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poster3/encode.py", line 312, in get_headers
    headers['Content-Length'] = str(get_body_size(params, boundary))
  File "/Users/teixeira/Downloads/Pessoal/etudes/etudes_py/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poster3/encode.py", line 303, in get_body_size
    size = sum(p.get_size(boundary) for p in MultipartParam.from_params(params))
  File "/Users/teixeira/Downloads/Pessoal/etudes/etudes_py/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poster3/encode.py", line 177, in from_params
    retval.append(cls(name=name, filename=filename,
  File "/Users/teixeira/Downloads/Pessoal/etudes/etudes_py/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poster3/encode.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.filename = self.filename.encode("string_escape").\
  AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Is this triggered there too ?

There seems to be the problem: `.encode("string_escape")` is legacy Python2 code: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings

If you still want to use this library, you can try removing lines 94 and 95 from `poster3/encode.py`:

```
self.filename = self.filename.encode("string_escape").\
    replace('"', '\\"')
```

And test :)

Comment: thanks for suggestion! I tried that, but got the same exception. Also, I realized I had an error in my description of execution and exception handling. I've updated my code and debug info above.

Comment: Thank you again Niloct! 1) This is not good news (that it is abandoned) 2) I had already worked around that issue in the library code you mentioned by indenting that line to reside under the else: clause.
May be time to move on...do you know other library solution to use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python may help